# SQL Server non-clustered index scan or index depending on value

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table that contains around 40 columns. In order to improve the query performance, I have created a non-clustered index with the key column of `Datetime` type which includes all the columns of the table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_index_date] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [datecolumn] ASC
)
INCLUDE([column1],[column2],...,[column40])
```

If I run a query like this with the option to show the execution plan:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable WHERE datecolumn > '2019-12-18 00:00:00.000'
```

Sometimes the executor uses an `index seek` (which is pretty fast, some seconds) and other times it uses an `index scan` (which can take up several minutes). The only difference appears to be on "how old" a date is. A query like the example always uses an `index scan`. But this query however:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable WHERE datecolumn > '2020-01-18 00:00:00.000'
```

Always uses an `index seek`. I don't understand why a change on the condition like this could end up with a seek or a scan.

I suspect there might not be enough information to detect the real issue but, could anyone point me to the underlying cause of this behavior?

Comment: Can you share both actual execution plans? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Does the execution plan have any lookup operators? (shouldn't do if the index is covering but check this). Is the table partitioned? In any event clearly you have missed out some vital information as selecting top 1 from an index seek should not take " some seconds" so I presume your actual query is more complex than shown

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for your comment. I just double-checked. The execution plan doesn't have any lookup operators (I think that's because I'm including all the columns on the index). Also, the table is not partitioned. The query is exactly like I shared. The SQL Server instance runs on Azure (Standard S4)

Comment: you need to share the execution plans then if you want an answer that actually explains it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the engine does not take your `TOP 1` into account (because without the TOP 1 it makes sense that a scan can be more efficient for an old date because it will return much more rows).

The reason is that you don't have an `ORDER BY` in your queries.  A `TOP 1` without `ORDER BY` is pretty confusing.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable WHERE datecolumn > '2020-01-18 00:00:00.000' ORDER BY datecolumn
```

Comment: Thanks @Wouter. That worked out, although I still don't understand the underlying reason why the "order by" makes the difference. I mean, isn't the date in the index already ordered? Why do I need to include an "order by"?

Comment: SQL Sever will take `TOP 1` into account unless using trace flag/query hint to suppress row goals. It also doesn't find it "pretty confusing" - there is something else going on that the OP hasn't shown us

Comment: A TOP 1 without ORDER BY does not make much sense. Even when you have an index on the date, it is not guaranteed that the first date is returned. Thats why you should add the order by.

Comment: yeah, I agree on that. but you said this was "the reason" for the performance difference

Answer (score 0):

Based on statistics sql server decides whether to seek an index or not. In the example you used * to fetch all the columns from the table. Provided that all the columns where included in the index ( which is not a good practice) There are always some over head of seeking the index so when you widen the range of predicate the sql server decides to full scan the index.